# Perl script 'WriteXLSX' failed to run successfully on RStudio - had status 127

Tags: r, perl

I recently switched computers at work and after redownloading R and RStudio and installing the required packages I get the following error message in the console in Rstudio:

> " running command 'perl
>   -I"C:/Users/lroy/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/WriteXLS/Perl" "C:/Users/lroy/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/WriteXLS/Perl/WriteXLSX.pl"
>   --CSVPath "C:\Users\lroy\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeQaBzc/WriteXLS" --verbose FALSE --AdjWidth TRUE --AutoFilter TRUE --BoldHeaderRow TRUE --FreezeRow 1 --FreezeCol 0 --Encoding UTF-8 "C:\Users\lroy\Desktop\Weekly Data Reporting\SureFire Trunk
>   Fiber\SureFire_New.xlsx"' had status 127 "

I am just learning R and am not an expert. The only thing that changed is the computer it runs on. All the scripts are the same.